# namespace package does not get installed as part of pip install

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

I am working on an open source package and have it published on pypi. I am using poetry to package and publish my project. My src tree structure is as below

```
- src
   |- novi
       |- client
       |    |- __init__.py
       |- core
       |    |- __init__.py
       |- web
       |    |- __init__.py    
   |- novi_activations
```

Both novi and novi_activations are python namespace packages and do not have an `__init__.py` directly underneath. My `pyproject.toml` is as below

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "novi"
version = "0.4.5"
description = "A simple yet powerful feature flag and multivariate testing platform built in Python"
authors = ["vdevigere <vdevigere+git@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    {include = "novi", from="src"},
]
include =[
    {path="src/novi_activations"}
]
.....
```

The resulting tar file has the right structure ie:- both novi and novi_activations get included. However when my users do a `pip install novi`. Only the novi package gets installed and not the novi_activations. I have tried a few things such as including novi_activations as a package instead

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "novi"
version = "0.4.5"
description = "A simple yet powerful feature flag and multivariate testing platform built in Python"
authors = ["vdevigere <vdevigere+git@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    {include = "novi", from="src"},
    {include = "novi_activations", from="src"}
]
......
```

However this fails with the error message that novi_activations is not a package. I can get over this by including some dummy packages under novi_activations but I dont want to do that. How do I get around this issue. If you are interested the code and pypi project links are below

- https://github.com/vdevigere/Novi
- https://pypi.org/project/novi/

Comment: What is in `src/novi_activations` that should be installed? If there is nothing to install in there, then nothing gets installed, and no need for *pip* to even create the `novi_activations` directory in the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: The idea is for end users to provide their own plugin modules in a folder named novi_activations. I am following the approach suggested here https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-namespace-packages

Comment: I see. It is not possible to provide an empty `novi_activations` directory (empty namespace package). The plugins have to provide the directory for the `novi_activations` namespace package themselves.